# Removing / Timing / Destroying out multiple php sessions variables at once

Tags: php, session, if-statement, session-variables, session-timeout

I'm trying to get several session variables to timeout / destroy at 30 minutes but using as minimal but effective code as possible.

Right now I have two solutions as follows:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fullname']) && (time() - $_SESSION['fullname'] > 1800)) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
$_SESSION['fullname'] = time();
```

---

```
  session_start();
  $user_inactive = 1800;
  $user_session = time() - $_SESSION['current_user'];
  if($user_session > $user_inactive) { 
     session_destroy(); 
     header("location: logout.php"); 
  }
  $_SESSION['current_user']=time();
```

---

Both these work fine for single variables, However i am trying to get this to destory several variables at the same time such as:

1. Fullname
2. Phonenumber
3. Emailaddress

**and so on...**

Could someone be kind enough to advise me on the best way to go about this in order to destroy multiple variables without having to duplicate my code over and over again for each variable.

Comment: `session_destroy()` is going to end your session, removing all of them.

Comment: It is better to have the entire session time out instead of clearing individual variables.  Partially clearing the session will be a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: i did think of using just session_destroy() on its own the but implications of that will be some of the other sessions i need to carry through will then become null and void. im just working on the code as i speak and one suspects maybe using a cookie to carry the other values that i need ive not yet quite worked that bit out yet so more than grateful for any ideas or thoughts. Thanks all.

Comment: `$delete = array('Fullname','Phonenumber','Emailaddress'); foreach($delete as $option) { unset($_SESSION[$option]); }`. Where the array items are the SESSION keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewLeaner as your aware from my last question i answered for you, I'm still learning the basics myself so i am far from experienced however i overcome a problem like this during the coding of my own application and [as Darren mentioned in a previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091482/removing-timing-destorying-out-multiple-php-sessions-variables-at-once#comment53999749_33091482), Having a list of variable values within an array will allow you to unset the relevant sessions accordingly based on the array values matching the session variable values.

Below is an example of your session variable values:

1. Fullname Session:       `$_SESSION['fullname']`
2. Phonenumber Session:    `$_SESSION['Phonenumber']`
3. Emailaddress Session:    `$_SESSION['Emailaddress']`

---

```
$unset = array('Fullname','Phonenumber','Emailaddress'); 
foreach( $unset as $sessions ) {
    unset($_SESSION[$sessions]); 
}
```

This will unset and remove the above sessions such as Fullname, Phonenumber, Emailaddress and any others you wish to add to the array.

You can add more Values to the array using single quotes and comma seperated, Here is an example to add further values.

```
$unset = array('Fullname','Phonenumber','Emailaddress', 'Variable_4', 'Variable_5', 'Variable_6', 'Variable_7', 'And so on...');
```

Hope this helps once again!

Comment: Yeah i did notice Darren original comment, i appreciate both the abbreviation and explanation of that and thanks for your time.

Comment: You get my +1 for giving credit and explaining the answer in depth more. Good work :)